# Java - RunTime Error. Не могу понять

Tags: java, runtime

Решаю задачи на сайте, при отправке сервер выдает Runtime error. Подозреваю, что при чтении данных. На машине все компилируется и работает, на сервере выдает ошибку Run Time error и на этом все.  В чем может быть дело и как её(ошибку) исправить? Спасибо.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Abc {
    static int[] sort(int[] a) {
        int[] temp;
        temp = a;

        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < temp.length; j++) {
                if (temp[j] > temp[i]) {
                    int t = temp[j];

                    temp[j] = temp[i];
                    temp[i] = t;
                }

            }
        }
        return temp;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scInt = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] inArray = new int[3];
        char[] ch = new char[3];

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            inArray[i] = scInt.nextInt();

        int[] outArray = sort(inArray);

        Scanner scString = new Scanner(System.in);
        String sb = scString.nextLine();
        scString.close();
        scInt.close();

        ch = sb.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            switch (ch[i]) {
            case 'A':
                System.out.print(outArray[0] + " ");
                break;

            case 'B':
                System.out.print(outArray[1] + " ");
                break;

            case 'C':
                System.out.print(outArray[2] + " ");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Используйте только один объект `Scanner` и не вызывайте `close` у него. Возможно, проблема исчезнет

Comment: оставил один сканер, тогда эту часть кода inArray[i] = scan.nextInt(); программа считывает хорошо, а вторую часть  String sb = scan.nextLine(); вообще не читает и далее на массиве switch (ch[i]) выдает ошибку ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException....

Comment: Приложи лог ошибки.

Comment: @Adelcoo вводите числа и текст одной строкой, после чего нажимайте Enter. А если очень хочется нажимать Enter после чисел, то `nextLine` надо вызвать дважды и брать результат второго

Comment: Спасибо всем за полезные советы.   Решил вопрос так:                       
           while (scan.hasNext()) {

   if (scan.hasNextInt()) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
     inArray[i] = scan.nextInt();
   } else {
    sb = scan.next();
    break;
   }

  }
  ;